# How to Handle Links with Blank Targets in Selenium Web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httpconnection

I was checking for the active links on the page..using htttpurlconnection.

I came across one situation.

U can see some links with target="_blank"

I do not want to include such links to the linkedlist. I tried to exclude the same using getattribute property of target.But it is not working.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICJS3.jpg

```
List <WebElement> activelinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();

for (int i=0;i<linkslist.size();i++) {

    system.out.println("link address of full links and images>>> " +  linkslist.get(i).getAttribute("href")); 

    if (linkslist.get(i).getAttribute("href")!=null && (linkslist.get(i).getAttribute("target")!="_blank" )) {
        activelinks.add(linkslist.get(i));
        System.out.println("active link " + 
        activelinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is performing filtering on [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) level, if you want to match links which:

- have `href` attribute

and

- have `target` attribute not equal to `_blank`

You can match such links as simple as:

```
//a[@href and not(@target='_blank')]
```

With regards to your approach, you should be using [String.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method for comparison, suggested code would be:

```
List<WebElement> activeLinks = linkslist
        .stream()
        .filter(link -> link.getAttribute("href") != null)
        .filter(link -> !link.getAttribute("target").equals("_blank"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```